# @AfterReturning(pointcut) vs @AfterReturning(value)

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

What is the difference between `@AfterReturning(pointcut)` and `@AfterReturning(value)`

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* my.java.model.Triangle.myTest*(param))", returning = "returnedString", argNames = "param,returnedString")
    public void afterReturningAdvice(String param, String returnedString) {
      System.out.println("Executing after function advice that accepts the input " + param + " and returns " + returnedString);
    }
```

The above method results in `Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 name binding only allowed in target, this, and args pcds`.

It works fine after replacing the above code with

```
@AfterReturning(value = "(* my.java.model.Triangle.myTest*(*))  && args(param)", returning = "returnedString", argNames = "param,returnedString")
  public void afterReturningAdvice(String param, String returnedString) {
    System.out.println("Executing after function advice that accepts the input " + param + " and returns " + returnedString);
  }
```

What is the difference between **value and pointcut**

Answer (score 2):

In fact when using the **pointcut** expression you override literary **value** clause when specified, you can copy your expression that specify where to bind the advice from value to pointcut and vice versa, check [here](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/aspectj5rt-api/org/aspectj/lang/annotation/AfterReturning.html)

You get the exception because the   AfterReturning bind implicitly only the returning value, if you want to bind any argument you must add   && args(param) to the first expression  :

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* my.java.model.Triangle.myTest*(String))  && args(param)" ..
```

Notice that i also change `execution(* my.java.model.Triangle.myTest*(param)` to `execution(* my.java.model.Triangle.myTest*(String)`
because **execution** (..) has nothing to do with binding argument to the advise, it only matches method execution join points.

Answer (score 0):

In the pointcut you can bind method arguments, `this()`, `target()`, `@annotation()`. This works in all advice types.

In `@AfterReturning` you can additionally bind the return value and in `@AfterThrowing` the thrown exception.

Method arguments and return value are not to be mistaken for each other.